# Ways to Compute Spectrum Matlab

Tags: matlab, fft, time-series

I have a question while computing the spectrum of a time series in Matlab. I have read the documentations concerning 'fft' function. However I have seen two ways of implementation and both wgive me different results. I would appreciate to have some answer about this difference:

1st Method:

```
nPoints=length(timeSeries);    
Time specifications:
Fs = 1; % samples per second
Fs = 50;
freq = 0:nPoints-1; %Numerators of frequency series
freq = freq.*Fs./nPoints;
% Fourier Transform:
X = fft(timeSeries)/nPoints; % normalize the data 
% find find nuquist frequency
cutOff = ceil(nPoints./2);
% take only the first half of the spectrum
X = abs(X(1:cutOff));
% Frequency specifications:
freq = freq(1:cutOff);
%Plot spectrum
semilogy(handles.plotLoadSeries,freq,X);
```

[image]

2nd Method:

```
NFFT = 2^nextpow2(nPoints); % Next power of 2 from length of y
Y = fft(timeSeries,NFFT)/nPoints;
f = 1/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);
% % Plot single-sided amplitude spectrum.
% plot(handles.plotLoadSeries, f,2*abs(Y(1:NFFT/2+1)))     
semilogy(handles.plotLoadSeries,f,2*abs(Y(1:NFFT/2+1)));
```

[image]

I thought that it is not necessary to use 'nextpow' function in 'fft' function in Matlab. Finally, which is the good one?

THanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The short answer:** you need [windowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) for spectrum analysis.

**Now for the long answer...** In the second approach, you are using an optimised FFT algorithm useful when the length of the input vector is a power of two. Let's assume that your original signal has 401 samples (as in my example below) from an infinitely long signal; `nextpow2()` will give you NFFT=512 samples. When you feed the shorter, 401-sample signal into the `fft()` function, it is implicitly zero-padded to match the requested length of 512 (`NFFT`). But (here comes the tricky part): zero-padding your signal is equivalent to multiplying an infinitely long signal by a [rectangular function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function), an operation that in the frequency domain translates to a convolution with a [sinc function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function). This would be the reason behind the increased noise floor at the bottom of your semilogarithmic plot.

A way to avoid this noise increase is to create manually the 512-sample signal you want to feed into `fft()`, using a smoother [window function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) instead of the default rectangular one. Windowing means just multiplying your signal by a tapered, symmetric one. There are tons of literature on choosing a good windowing function, but a typically accurate one with low sidelobes (low noise increase) is the [Hamming function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#Hamming_window), implemented in MATLAB as `hamming()`.

Here is a figure illustrating the issue (in the frequency domain and time domain):

[image: Windowing and spectrum analysis]

...and the code to generate this figure:

```
clear

% Create signal
fs = 40;           % sampling freq.
Ts = 1/fs;         % sampling period
t = 0:Ts:10;       % time vector
s = sin(2*pi*3*t); % original signal
N = length(s);

% FFT (length not power of 2)
S = abs(fft(s)/N);
freq = fs*(0:N-1)/N;

% FFT (length power of 2)
N2 = 2^nextpow2(N);
S2 = abs(fft(s, N2)/N2);
freq2 = fs*(0:N2-1)/N2;
t2 = (0:N2-1)*Ts;       % longer time vector
s2 = [s,zeros(1,N2-N)]; % signal that was implicitly created for this FFT

% FFT (windowing before FFT)
s3 = [s.*hamming(N).',zeros(1,N2-N)];
S3 = abs(fft(s3, N2)/N2);

% Frequency-domain plot
figure(1)
subplot(211)
cla
semilogy(freq,S);
hold on
semilogy(freq2,S2,'r');
semilogy(freq2,S3,'g');
xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
ylabel('FFT')
grid on
legend( 'FFT[401]', 'FFT[512]', 'FFT[512] with windowing' )

% Time-domain plot
subplot(212)
cla
plot(s)
hold on
plot(s3,'g')
xlabel('Index')
ylabel('Amplitude')
grid on
legend( 'Original samples', 'Windowed samples' )
```